# Regular expression for anchor tags in same line

Tags: regex, anchor

```
/<a .*href.*>/ig
```

is a simple regex which selects strings like:

```
<a href>
<a href="www.example.com">
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click me</a>
<a href="www.google.com" > click me</a>
<A href="www.123-xyz.com" > click me</a>
```

However it also selects the following as a single string:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"> www.google.com</a><a href="www.google.com" >click me</a>
```

Is there any way that the above be selected as 2 different strings as in:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"> www.google.com</a>
<a href="www.google.com" >click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `*` quantifiers are *greedy*; make them `*?` *reluctant* (consume as little input as possible to make a match):

```
/<a .*?href.*?>/ig
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/GQ8Lk0VEsG).

Answer (score 1):

Try [this Regex:](https://regex101.com/r/tR6kX8/4)

`<a\s[^>]*>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Look @ match-4. It gives me 2 anchor tags as one string where as the question states that these should be 2 different strings. Besides, I only nees the opening anchor tags that have an href attribute.